# Dual boot SCSI Drivers?

Tags: multi-boot, scsi

I am about to try a dual boot set up. I just got my Windows XP CD in the mail. So from what I understand it seems fairly simple.

However, I run my set up in RAID 0 and during the XP install I see this prompt asking to install 3rd party SCSI drivers. I somehow remember this being important and know that Windows 7 handles it automatically so it's never been an issue. My question is where do I find the SCSI Drivers I need for my dual raptor 10k rpm hard drivers and what is the best way to install them?

Is this something I should be concerned with or does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if XP setup can see your hard drives, you don't need to install anything.  If XP can't see your hard drives, you have a bigger issue.  Whoever manufactured your SATA controller would have to provide you with the appropriate drivers, and you could then follow the procedure that came with them to make a floppy appropriate for Windows XP.

If you don't have a floppy drive, there are some ways around that - for example, there's a tutorial on inserting drivers onto the Windows XP cd [here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Install-Windows-XP-On-SATA-Without-a-Floppy-F6-47807.shtml).

I'm assuming that you're using SATA, not parallel or serial SCSI drives, but the procedure would be the same in the case of a SCSI controller.